# How to create a key by JPA annotation (not primary key, just key)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

If there is a table creating statement like

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What annotation should I use to implement `` KEY `username` (`username`) ``?
I've try looking up annotations in javax.persistence but no result.

Comment: Use `@Index` and `@table` annotations on the class.

Answer (score 1):

Fine, I solved this question by myself with using

```
columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(64) KEY"
```

Please let me know if anyone has a better idea.